# TCP connect: No route to host

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I started a tcp server on a host A and then start a tcp client on another host B.

Both hosts are in the same LAN via the wireless router at home.
the tcp client tries to connect to tcp server on port 8000. but it failed due to " No route to host"

I can ping successfully the server host from the client host, and actually I'm ssh'ed into the server from the client now

If I swap the two hosts, namely I started the tcp server on the host B and then start the tcp client on the host A. then the TCP connection is successful

What is wrong with the server host A? 
the following link shows the results of iptables -L -n, ss -tlnp and netstat -lnp

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12785409/

and routing table on A:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

routing table on B:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

The related tcp client and server are:
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f99/www/class26/tcpserver.c

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f99/www/class26/tcpclient.c

I tried

kill vpnagent process

```
# ps ax | grep vpnagent 
1291 ? S 0:00 /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpnagentd 
4202 pts/2 S+ 0:00 grep --color=auto vpnagent
#sudo kill -9 1291
```

and then

```
# service vpnagentd stop
# sudo systemctl stop vpnagentd
```

and I don't know is it due to this, last day, the connection suddenly become OK. But after I reboot, run the above commands to stop vpnagent service, the "No route to host" problem is still there

Comment: Isn't port 8000 being blocked by the firewall rules? SSH is being allowed because there is a rule for it (port 22).

Comment: @teikjoon wher e is blocking 8000? and how can I make it not block 8000?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae  ah, I have modified the links and you can check them now. they are source codes, not routing tables. what any other info should I provide to trouble-shoot the problem? thanks

Comment: @ MariusMatutiae I have updated the routing table, is it right? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fedora is using firewalld service for port blocking/allowing

Use this command to find your active zone(s):

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
```

It will say either public, dmz, or something else. You should only apply to the zones required.

In the case of public try:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8000/tcp
```

if you want to make it permanent, try:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8000/tcp --permanent
```

Otherwise, substitute dmz for your zone, for example, if your zone is public:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2888/tcp --permanent
```

Then remember to reload the firewall for changes to take effect.

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: What if `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones` returns nothing? What to do?